# ¿Cómo defino el tipo de letra que se ve en toda la página con Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Para un proyecto con Vuejs estoy utilizando Bootstrap. Quiero que todo el texto utilice una fuente determinada, digamos Arial, y me gustaría definirlo en un lugar único.

Dado que toda la aplicación cuelga de un `<div id="#app">` genérico, se me ocurre decir lo siguiente en mi fichero css:

```
#app {
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Sin embargo, en otros lugares veo que se puede definir con:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Lo probé pero hay lugares donde no funciona, incluso poniendo `!important` al final.

Y [en otros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076928/1983854) veo que podría decir:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

¿Cuál de ellos es el "correcto"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@font-face` lo usas para traer una fuente, desde un cdn o un fichero local, un ejemplo sería así:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "MyHelvetica";
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold"),
  local("HelveticaNeue-Bold"),
  url(MgOpenModernaBold.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Con esto creas una familia que se llama MyHelvetica. Puedes crear varias familias diferentes.
Después en el body dices qué familia usar, así:

```
body {
    font-family: "MyHelvetica";
}
```

Si quisieras aplicar un tipo de fuente distinto a un elemento en concreto, lo usarías con el selector correspondiente. "body" es un selector al igual que "#app", etc.

Arial ya viene integrada por lo que no tienes que importarla de ningún lado, eso lo usas cuando son fuentes externas. [fonts.googleapis.com](https://fonts.google.com) tiene un montón.

Sobre lo de `!important`, se usa cuando aplicas a un mismo elemento dos atributos distintos, y quieres que uno prevalezca por los demás. No se debe abusar de !important, lo correcto es cargar los ficheros css en el orden adecuado.
Por ejemplo, si el bootstrap.css tiene ciertos estilos, pero tú quieres modificarlos, deberías primero cargar el bootstrap.css en head del html y en la siguiente línea cargar tu propio fichero.css sobrescribiendo las clases de bootstrap que quieras cambiar.

Comment: vale de hecho no es Arial sino Roboto, que no sé si está en las fuentes por defecto

Comment: no, Roboto hay que importarla. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto:wght@100&query=roboto&sidebar.open haz clic donde pone "@import" y añade eso en la primera línea a tu css.

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');

Luego la usas globalmente a todo el body (que alberga tu #app y hederdará este valor) así
body {
font-family: 'Roboto';
}

Comment: Genial, gracias. No encontré donde pone "@import" pero añadiendo `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i');
` me funcionó bien. Una duda: ¿cómo sabes qué fuentes vienen de serie y cuáles hay que importar?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' las "fuentes de serie" (no sé si sea el nombre correcto), son las que vienen instaladas inicialmente con el OS que trae el equipo en donde estés viendo el proyecto. Por ejemplo, si en tu pagina web usas la fuente Segoe UI, y la visitas desde un PC Windows, no necesitas importarla, pero, cuando la veas por ej, en un iPad, no va a cargar dicha fuente. Lo mismo pasa con las fuentes exclusivas de Apple, como Lucida Grande. Otro caso es la fuente Roboto propia de Google, no necesitarías importarla si únicamente la vas a usar en dispositivos Android.

Comment: Wikipedia recoge varios listados donde puedes echar un vistazo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_typefaces

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @JheymanMejia por la información

Comment: @JheymanMejia ¿te parece que publique una pregunta diferente para esto? Así tiene más visibilidad y puedo darte unos merecidos +25

Comment: Gracias, @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Quise extenderme en una respuesta, pero no me animé al final. Si añades una nueva pregunta relacionada con los `@import` y el uso de fuentes, con gusto la contestaría.

Comment: Ya la publiqué, @JheymanMejia [¿Cómo sé qué fuentes tiene un sistema y las importo o no a la hora de cargar una página?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/355899/83)