# ¿Por qué el navegador no me toma las tipografías que importe en el código?

Tags: fuentes, google-fonts, font-faces

como estan?
Basicamente mi pregunta es esa.

Descargue familias tipográficas de Google Fonts, las inserté en el archivo css por ej. de la siguiente manera, asi con cada una:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BebasNeue-Regular";
    src: url(/fonts/Bebas_Neue/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf);
}
```

Y la use asi:

```
h4 {
    font-family: "BebasNeue-Regular";
}
```

Ahora en el navegador cuando pruebo la pagina se ve que toma una tipografía, pero no es esa. Y no logro saber porque es que me usa otra. Porque no creo que haya fallas en el archivo que descargué.

Ojala alguno sepa.

Saludos!

Comment: De pronto te sirve de referencia esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355899/c%c3%b3mo-s%c3%a9-qu%c3%a9-fuentes-tiene-un-sistema-y-si-debo-importarlas-o-no-a-la-hora-de-ca/355999#355999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Busca y selecciona la tipografía.
2. Incrustar la tipografia (con import o link)

- Si usas el **link** simplemente la tienes que poner en el html **antes de cargar** el css con `href`.
- Si usas import pues igual pero con `@import url('')`

Si ese no es el problema, mira más [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355899/c%C3%B3mo-s%C3%A9-qu%C3%A9-fuentes-tiene-un-sistema-y-si-debo-importarlas-o-no-a-la-hora-de-ca/355999#355999) sobre como utilizar las fuentes y demás.

Comment: Si, mi idea era no usar @imports o links pero fue lo unico que me lo solucionó. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Genial, para eso estamos!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías aplicar el código de la siguiente manera: dado que las web trabajan con varias extensiones para las fuentes: woff2, woff, ttd y eot

```css
@font-face {
            font-family: 'BebasNeue-Regular';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('BebasNeue-Regular'),
            url('/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
            url('/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
    
        }
            h4{
                font-family: "BebasNeue-Regular";
            }
```

```html
<h4>Prueba de Fuente de texto</h4>
```